# Openshift with lombok issue

Tags: java, maven, openshift, lombok

I create a new application with the template of openshift with wildfly 8, and everything works fine.

After I add the `lombok:1.16.4` library, the maven in the server doesn't compile, in my local machine it works fine.

When I run `mvn -e -Popenshift -DskipTests -X compile` in the openshift machine, it says me:

```
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d
/var/lib/openshift/ID/app-root/runtime/repo/target/classes
-classpath
/var/lib/openshift/ID/app-root/runtime/repo/target/classes:/var/lib/openshift/ID/.m2/repository/javax/javaee-api/7.0/javaee-api-7.0.jar:/var/lib/openshift/ID/.m2/repository/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.5.0/javax.mail-1.5.0.jar:/var/lib/openshift/ID/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/var/lib/openshift/ID/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.4/lombok-1.16.4.jar:/var/lib/openshift/ID/.m2/repository/org/torpedoquery/org.torpedoquery/1.7.0/org.torpedoquery-1.7.0.jar:/var/lib/openshift/ID/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.0-GA/javassist-3.18.0-GA.jar:/var/lib/openshift/ID/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/javax.persistence/2.0.0/javax.persistence-2.0.0.jar:/var/lib/openshift/ID/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/1.3/objenesis-1.3.jar:/var/lib/openshift/ID/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.2/guava-11.0.2.jar:/var/lib/openshift/ID/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/var/lib/openshift/ID/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.0/commons-lang3-3.0.jar:
-sourcepath
/var/lib/openshift/ID/app-root/runtime/repo/src/main/java:
ALL_MY_CLASSES
-s /var/lib/openshift/ID/app-root/runtime/repo/target/generated-sources/annotations
-g -nowarn -target 1.8 -source 1.8 -encoding UTF-8
```

And a compilation error, the problem is, that when I run

```
javac $ALL_ARGUMENTS_FROM_MAVEN_DEBUG_INFO (from the -d)
```

It works fine, and a post javac manually compilation `mvn compile` report no problems (until a `clean` is executed, or a file is changed).

I check the variables in the environment and I don't see anything wrong, this are the differences:

- mvn: local (3.2.3) remote (3.0.4)
- os:  local (amd64) remote (i386)
- os.version: local (3.16) remote (2.6)
- both using OpenJDK
- aether: local (org.eclipse.aether) remote (org.sonatype.aether)

Also, if I remove the `lombok` part in the classpath when I run the `javac` command, I get the same error from maven.

What can be the difference between the environment that make the maven from openshift *ignore* lombok?

[Here](https://www.diffchecker.com/xxrdlwrl) is the link to the two compilations (with debug output)

Comment: My guess is that Maven isn't _ignoring_ lombok, but rather it cannot properly use it.  The possible cause is that the server has an extra dependency of lombok which is incorrectly being loaded.

Comment: Compare _all_ dependencies on your local machine and the server.  I am fairly certain you will see some differences.  I don't think the Maven/JDK version differences are the root cause of your problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the `org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac` is differente (1.8.1 in openshift, and 2.2 in my local machine), but I think this is related to the maven version. Check the update please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the `maven-compiler-plugin`, with the latest version it works everywhere, add this to the pom:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

The version of the plugin in the default configuration in openshift is too old (2.3) and don't work well with lombok.